# No strings available. when translating a menu item in drupal

Tags: drupal, translation

I'm trying to translate the menu items in drupal, but when I go to the Translate interface and type a menu item in, I just get "No strings available."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only hard coded strings are available to string translation, in order to translate menu item defined in your menu, you need i18n.